# In Gwt project to pay with PayPal I exit from the page so I lose the login

Tags: java, paypal, server, gwt-rpc, express-checkout

I have a project in GWT-RPC, where users logged can buy things with PayPal express checkout in sandbox mode . When I'm redirected to PayPal, I exit from the page, so I lose my authentication and when I return on the return url after the interaction with PayPal the user is log out. I would want remain login but I don't know how to do it. 
I'm running my project on eclipse in this moment of development. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to getting logged out of your system or application, you could store your session in your database, and then pass over session identifier in the API call for Express Checkout.  Then once the user is returned, use the session identifier that you passed over.  You could pass this identifier over in the variable "custom", which is a pass through variable.

Comment: Thanks! In my db are stored all the users dates. Would you suggest to use  the username as identifier (in order to identify the user and obtain the password to login) or another way?

Comment: You could pass over what every you are wanting to use for an identifier.  It just needs to be something that allows you to map it back to that session in your DB.  The custom variable allows for 256 single-byte alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your answer!